# Как сделать вертикальный nav c dropdown group?

Tags: bootstrap, html, javascript, css

Как сделать вертикальный `nav` как здесь http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills но с `dropdown` кнопкой справа??

[image: скрин]

Comment: [покажите][1] что у вас уже есть. А вообще-то [вот же есть][2] пример.


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net
  [2]: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jPn2m/ дропдаун должен быть справа, баттон не подходит, нужен именно нав

Comment: типа [такого][1]?


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jPn2m/1/

Comment: отлично, но вот ещё бы косячок пожправить http://prntscr.com/23w5iy кнопки из-за z-index перекрывают dropdown menu и хотелось бы span со стрелкой правее drop-а

Comment: как сделать чтобы кнопки не перекрывали дроп меню??

Answer (score 1):

Может [так попробуете](http://jsfiddle.net/jPn2m/2/)... А вот [пример без стрелочек](http://jsfiddle.net/jPn2m/3/) справа.

```css
.btn-group {
    float: right;
    margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
.btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle {
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 34px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="list-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <a href='#' class="list-group-item active">                    
            <div>
                test nav
                <span class='float-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
            </div>                   
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <a href='#' class="list-group-item active">                    
            <div>
                test nav
                <span class='float-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
            </div>                   
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <a href='#' class="list-group-item active">                    
            <div>
                test nav
                <span class='float-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
            </div>                   
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```